# Xamarin Android Player : OpenGL server is unreachable

Tags: opengl, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin-android-player

Now I'm facing an error while starting **Xamarin Android Player**.

**Error : OpenGL server is unreachable. Please check that Xamarin Android Player is allowed through your firewall on public networks.**

I'm using **Windows8.1 (64-bit)**.
Xamarin Android Player is allowed on public networks.
The screen shots of the errors are attached with this.

Is there any way to get rid of this error !

**Screen shot 01**
[image]

**Screen shot 02**

[image]

**Screen shot 03**[image]

Comment: Do you have another emulator that uses VM like Genymotion? if yes then there must be a conflict of settings, you can try this:
1.Uninstall previous versions of Xamarin Android Player
2.Open up VirtualBox and remove all of the Xamarin Android Player devices, choose to delete files.
3.Open the VirtualBox Virtual Media Manager and ensure there are no data.vdi, system.vdi or sdcard.vdi files remaining. If there are, release and remove them.
4.Delete \Library\XAP
5. install Xamarin Android Player again

Comment: @CDrosos : Let me try it.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error all the time. What fixed it for me was closing adb.exe. Go to task manager and close adb.exe before restarting Xamarin.

If that doesn't work, try to reinstall the host only network adapters in Virtualbox. Open virtualbox -> File -> preferences -> Network -> Host only. And remove all the adapters. Then restart Xamarin. It will prompt to reinstall the adapters. Click Ok.

Answer (score 1):

McAfee antivirus blocks Player if you have installed, I tried to stop and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in mac OS, in my case I already had virtual box with different network configurations from previous VMs that were causing this issue.
To fix this I had to set the host only network to the appropriate values.

1. In the VirtualBox settings of the Android Emulator VM, inside the Network Tab -> Adapter 1 verify the name of your host-only adapter (in my case vboxnet0)

[image]

2. With that name in mind navigate to VirtualBox VM -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks and double click the one selected in step 1.
3. Set the following values:

[image: Adapter Tab]
[image: DHCP Server Tab]